# Databinding with C# and Mysql shows wrong data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have just created my first WPF-application and connected it to MySql-database. 
I am able to retrieve data from DB, but it presents it totally wrong

I have searched through internet and different threads and now I have tried different things for a couple of hours.

My XAML-file

```
   <Window x:Class="AppGetMySQL.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppGetMySQL"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Get All Records" Height="450" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Width="800" AllowsTransparency="False" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow">
<Window.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF1F7FF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Window.Background>
<Grid Margin="0,-52,0,0">
    <Button Content="Connect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" Height="41" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="126,170,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="ListAllUsers" Width="527" Height="291" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Calibri">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="300px"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="City" Width="300px" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

My .cs-file

```
int x = 0;

string connectionString = "SERVER=db5.freemysqlhosting.net;" + "DATABASE=db5233941;" + "UID=db5233941;" + "PASSWORD=*******;";
        string query = "select * from AllUsers";//I know I should not use *, but this is just test.
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        MySqlDataAdapter ada = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ada.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
            List<String> stringList = new List<string>();
            stringList.Add(dr["Id"].ToString());
            stringList.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
            stringList.Add(dr["City"].ToString());
            ListAllUsers.ItemsSource = stringList;
        }
```

I hope to print something like:

> | id | Name | City |
>
> | id | Name | City |
>
> | id | Name | City |

But instead it prints

> | id | id | id |
>
> | Name | Name | Name |
>
> | City | City | City |

Picture:

[image: How it gets printed]

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Actually when I add this in the loop:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Id: " + dr["Id"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + dr["Name"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("City: " + dr["City"].ToString());
```

It prints everything correct. All five rows I have in my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, and posts the solution if anybody needs it later.

I changed this in my xaml:

```
                <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id"   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="300px"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  />
                <GridViewColumn Header="City" Width="300px" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding City}"  />
                </GridView>
```

And used this in my .cs-file

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
            ListAllUsers.Items.Add(new User() {Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]), Name = dr["Name"].ToString(), City = dr["City"].ToString() });
            ...
```

This was all I needed to change.

Hope the next one will have some need of this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the binding somehow. Compare to this tutorial page, that might help. [ListView with a GridView](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/) Exerpt:

```
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

Comment: Now I got the error:  `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Id' property not found on 'object' ''String'`